# passing variable value through php function not working

Tags: php

i am trying to pass the value of `$page="somepage";` throught a function suppose

```
function example($page)

        {
                    echo $page;
   ?>
   <input type="radio" name="smoke" value="Y"> Yes
   <input type="radio" class="ml_10" name="smoke" value="N"> No
   <input type="radio" class="ml_10" name="smoke" value="O"> Occasionally
   <?php
        }

example ($page);
```

When i try to echo the page it should come as `somepage` but instead its coming `1`. but if i manually write page while calling functions it prints right for eg `example ("somepage")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$page` variable contains number 1 before calling `example()` function
So, you have to make it contain "somepage" value instead.

OR

your `example()` function contains some code that converts "somepage" to 1.

most likely its something like

```
$page = include $page;
```

line which you omit from your question for some unknown reason

Either way question being too localized and thus not suitable for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

As long as you declare `$page` before calling the function, what you're trying to do will work.

```
$page = "somepage";

example($page);


function example($page)

{
    echo $page;
    ?>
    <input type="radio" name="smoke" value="Y"> Yes
    <input type="radio" class="ml_10" name="smoke" value="N"> No
    <input type="radio" class="ml_10" name="smoke" value="O"> Occasionally
    <?php
}
```

Comment: i am declaring the $page at top of the page and calling the function at bottom

Comment: @user1001176 That is fine, but make sure the value of $page is staying consistent through the script. Are you assigning it to a boolean value at any point?

Comment: no i am not i really dont know why is this happening i mean my code is right i know that all my functions are stopped i was passing value of page in all of them . any quick fix to this ?

Comment: @user1001176 Upload the entire code, that's the only way I'd be able to find your issue.